# Changing default materializecss colors in Meteorjs

Tags: css, meteor, materialize

In it's official [site](http://materializecss.com/sass.html):

> When using Sass, you can change the color scheme of your site
>   extremely quickly. Below is a very small sample of what you can change
>   through sass in _variables.scss.

But how can I change default colours for materialize:materialize (materializecss.com) package for meteor?

Comment: According to this thread it may not be possible (or at least straightforward): https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/1018. But I have not played around with trying.

Comment: Checkout https://ghariaonline.wordpress.com/2016/03/14/materialize-css-changing-default-theme-with-sass/

Answer (score 3):

Easiest thing to do would be to install 
https://github.com/fourseven/meteor-scss as a package using `meteor add fourseven:scss`.
Then add the source .scss version from http://materializecss.com/getting-started.html into your /client folder in your app, where you can change the variables in ._variables.scss.

Meteor and the `fourseven:scss` package will compile the scss and the javascript for you.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but how to avoid than, that the CSS was loaded twice? (one from meteor package one time the local one?)

Comment: @james what files I need to add to that folder?

Answer (score 1):

The official materialize package for meteor does not contain the SASS source files, so you will either have to create a package to utilize the SASS files or just link up materialize the ole fashioned way. There also is a package that contains the SASS source and instructions on how to override the colors and what not. https://atmospherejs.com/grigio/materialize-sass. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

After doing some research I figured this has been discussed on github already.

It could be done by 1) adding meteor scss version; 2) import it in your scss file.

```
$ meteor add fourseven:scss
$ meteor add poetic:materialize-scss
$ meteor remove materialize:materialize # if you have materialize installed
```

You should place this code in your **client/styles/app.scss**:

```
@import ".meteor/local/build/programs/server/assets/packages/poetic_materialize-scss/bower_components/materialize/sass/components/_color.scss";
@import "client/styles/variables.scss";
@import ".meteor/local/build/programs/server/assets/packages/poetic_materialize-scss/bower_components/materialize/sass/materialize.scss";
```

**client/styles/variables.scss**

```
$primary-color-dark:   #846C63;
$primary-color:        #4CAF50;
$primary-color-light:  #C8E6C9;
$primary-color-text:   #FFFFFF;
$accent-color:         #388E3C;
$primary-text-color:   #212121;
$secondary-text-color: #727272;
$divider-color:        #B6B6B6;
```

(obvisouly chance the palette ;-) )

Source: https://github.com/poetic/meteor-materialize-sass/issues/1

Comment: These instructions are out of date. Use https://github.com/poetic/meteor-materialize-scss/ instead.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a workaround for editing the `materialize:materialize` package SASS variables.

1. Install using `meteor add materialize:materialize`
2. Download the SASS package files from `http://materializecss.com/bin/materialize-src-v0.97.7.zip`
3. Place **the CSS files ONLY** in your `/client` folder. See image below:

[image]

4. Edit any of the styles within the `/component` directory and you will see this reflected in your view.

> Note: you do not have to import any javascript files. The `materialize:materialize` package will handle that for you.